# Counter using foreach in php

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, count

I'm trying to get my counter to, well, count. I'm trying to add a classname (even) to every second post displayed using the following:

```
<?php
        global $paged;
        global $post;
        $do_not_duplicate = array();
        $categories = get_the_category();
        $category = $categories[0];
        $cat_ID = $category->cat_ID;
        $myposts = get_posts('category='.$cat_ID.'&paged='.$paged);
        $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;
        $c = 0;
        $c++;
        if( $c == 2) {
            $style = 'even animated fadeIn';
            $c = 0;
        }
        else $style='animated fadeIn';
        ?>

<?php foreach($myposts as $post) :?>
   // Posts outputted here
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I just don't get the `even` classname being outputted. The only classnames that get outputted are `animated` and `FadeIn` classes (from the else part of my if statement) are added to every post at the moment with

Comment: Use the modulus operator: `if (($c++ % 2) == 0) {` but do it `inside` your foreach loop

Comment: `$c` looks like it will always be 1.  You might want to move your if statement inside of your `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this part of your code:

```
    $c = 0;
    $c++;
    if( $c == 2) {
        $style = 'even animated fadeIn';
        $c = 0;
    }
    else $style='animated fadeIn';
```

You need to put the increment and `if-else` block inside the `foreach` loop. Like this:

```
<?php foreach($myposts as $post) :
    $c++;
    if( $c % 2 == 0) {
        $style = 'even animated fadeIn';
        $c = 0;
    }
    else $style='animated fadeIn'; ?>
   // Posts outputted here
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Just the ticket. Thanks for your help! Explained well so understood it perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

check out the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Also, move your even/odd check to your posts loop.

```
<?php $i = 0; foreach($myposts as $post) :?>
    <div class="<?php echo $i % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd'; ?>">
        // Posts outputted here
    </div>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you dont set the counter back to 2 in your else statement.

```
if( $c == 2) {
  $style = 'even animated fadeIn';
  $c = 0;
} else {
  $style='animated fadeIn';
  $c = 2;
}
```

That being said, you could also use the modulo as others mentioned or simply do:

```
//outside loop
$c = 1;


//inside loop
if ($c==1)
  $style = 'even animated fadeIn';
else
  $style='animated fadeIn';
$c = $c * -1;
```

or even shorter

```
//outside
$c = 1;

//inside
$style = (($c==1)?'even':'').' animated fadeIn';
$c = $c * -1;
```